# Division in $A[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

I was looking for a division in a ring of formal power series. Specifically, let be $A$ a commutative ring with unit. Take $A[[x]]$ and $f\in A[x]$ a monic polynomial not invertible in $A[[x]]$ is so defined a division in $A[[x]]$ for f?

for each $h$ in $A[[x]]$ there $\exists!$ r in $A[x]$ and $q \in A[[x]]$ such that h=fg+r and $degr < degf$

for example is trivial is $f(t)=t^N$:

Comment: What properties do you want for your "division"?

Comment: I'm sorry don't think..

Comment: Check your spelling!

Answer (score 3):

This cannot always be done. I'm afraid I'm nowhere near to getting to the root cause of the problem. Instead I will just show an example.

---

Let $A=\Bbb{Z}$, $f=x-3$ and $h=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$. If your goal were attainable then there should exist a constant $r\in\Bbb{Z}$ and a power series
$$
q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty q_ix^i\in\Bbb{Z}[[x]]
$$
such that
$$
h=r+(x-3)q(x).\qquad(*)
$$
This turns into a system of equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
1&=r-3q_0,\\
1&=q_i-3q_{i+1},&\text{for all $i$.}
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
r=1+3q_0=4+9q_1=13+27q_2=\cdots.
$$
In other words
$$
r=1+3+9+27+\cdots+3^k+3^{k+1}q_k\equiv\sum_{j=0}^k3^j\pmod{3^{k+1}}
$$
for all $k$. Therefore
$$
-2r=(1-3)r=\cdots\equiv1\pmod{3^{k+1}}
$$
for all $k$.

But, $n=1$ is the only integer congruent to $1$ modulo $3^k$ for all $k$. As $-2r\in\Bbb{Z}$, we can conclude that $-2r=1$. As $r$ is also an integer, this is absurd.

Comment: I guess the point is that we can always find a polynomial $q_m$ such that $(*)$ holds up to terms of degree $x_m$. But the sequence of polynomials $(q_m)$ does not converge to a limit $q\in\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$. I think there is more to this, but it's getting late, and I am not man enough to grasp this.

Comment: Another possibility may be to approach this using the inverse of $f$ in $\Bbb{Q}[[x]]$. Using another commutative ring $A$ in place of $\Bbb{Z}$ may give easier examples.